# Building workspace vs uploading cartridges in eclipse in code deployment over sandbox

Tags: salesforce, sandbox

I am deploying a code over sandbox from eclipse, I'm new to salesforce development.
what is the diff between building workspace and  uploading cartridges in eclipse.
I appreciate all the help that i can get, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are no "cartidges" in Salesforce documentation. Are you sure you're developing salesforce code? Maybe you're working on some Java integration? Or maybe you mean packages? zip files with package.xml and source code?

And Eclipse development model is outdated now, all the cool kids moved on to sfdx + visual studio code. What you're doing still works (it uses "metadata api") but you're consciously using old tools, depriving yourself from newer, faster toys. You can read more about metadata api style of deployments in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm

Now... If you ask about "why do I bother with doing deployments if in sandbox I can just edit the class/trigger directly and save"... well - you can't in production. You can't just go and edit code straight on production, even in the setup the button simply isn't there. It has to be a deployable package, it has to run unit tests during deploy (they need to pass, the code coverage has to be at least 75%). So you make a package when you're really ready to go to prod

Comment: Cartridges are a Commerce Cloud extension model, Eclipse is a possible IDE for dev work in this context. See https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/b2c-cartridges/b2c-cartridges-explore for more info

Comment: Ha, ok then. You didn't tag it salesforce-commerce-cloud. In that case consider cross-posting to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/, bigger chance a specialist will see it?